# rails RSolr::Error::ConnectionRefused: Connection refused error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I'm working on a API project using rails 5 and I've installed **sunspot** gem for searching but now i get the error

RSolr::Error::ConnectionRefused: Connection refused

in the rails console when i try to change any field in a record or create new record
the full error log :

```
RSolr::Error::ConnectionRefused: Connection refused - {:data=>"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><add><doc><field name=\"id\">Event 147</field><field name=\"type\">Event</field><field name=\"type\">ApplicationRecord</field><field name=\"type\">ActiveRecord::Base</field><field name=\"class_name\">Event</field><field boost=\"5\" name=\"title_text\">new Event around</field><field name=\"desc_text\">something</field><field name=\"location_text\">12134</field></doc></add>", :headers=>{"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}, :method=>:post, :params=>{:wt=>:ruby}, :query=>"wt=ruby", :path=>"update", :uri=>#<URI::HTTP http://localhost:8982/solr/development/update?wt=ruby>, :open_timeout=>nil, :read_timeout=>nil, :retry_503=>nil, :retry_after_limit=>nil}
    from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rsolr-1.1.1/lib/rsolr/connection.rb:19:in `rescue in execute'
    from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rsolr-1.1.1/lib/rsolr/connection.rb:14:in `execute'
    from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rsolr-1.1.1/lib/rsolr/client.rb:181:in `execute'
    from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rsolr-1.1.1/lib/rsolr/client.rb:175:in `send_and_receive'
    from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.5/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
    from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
    from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
    from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
    from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.5/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in `send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
    from (eval):2:in `post'
    from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rsolr-1.1.1/lib/rsolr/client.rb:84:in `update'
    from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rsolr-1.1.1/lib/rsolr/client.rb:104:in `add'
    from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sunspot-2.2.5/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:127:in `add_documents'
    from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sunspot-2.2.5/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:134:in `add_batch_documents'
    from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sunspot-2.2.5/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:26:in `add'
    from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sunspot-2.2.5/lib/sunspot/session.rb:91:in `index'
... 29 levels...
        from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
        from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
        from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /home/mcd/RailsProjects/carpool/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
        from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
        from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
        from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /home/mcd/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

and in my gem file i'm including

```
gem 'sunspot_rails'
```

and in the development group

```
gem 'sunspot_solr'
gem 'progress_bar'
```

Update: 
when i try to reindex

```
    RSolr::Error::ConnectionRefused: Connection refused - {:data=>"<?xml   version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delete><query>type:Event</query></delete>", :headers=>{"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}, :method=>:post, :params=>{:wt=>:ruby}, :query=>"wt=ruby", :path=>"update", :uri=>#<URI::HTTP http://localhost:8982/solr/development/update?wt=ruby>, :open_timeout=>nil, :read_timeout=>nil, :retry_503=>nil, :retry_after_limit=>nil}
(eval):2:in `post'
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:8982 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 8982)
(eval):2:in `post'
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 8982
(eval):2:in `post'
Tasks: TOP => sunspot:solr:reindex => sunspot:reindex
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've forgot to run the command

```
rake sunspot:solr:run
```

Hope that helps someone new with sunspot/solr such as myself

Comment: `rake sunspot:solr:run` is great for debugging. You can also run `rake sunspot:solr:start` to get it up standalone. If you are running specs you will need to run  `RAILS_ENV=test rake sunspot:solr:start `